# What is the difference between these two sql statements(JDBC)?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I want to get last id in table. First I did this:

```
String selectId = "SELECT MAX(id) FROM book_store.cart" ;    
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(selectId);  
rs =  ps.executeQuery();
while(rs.next()){
    autoIncKey = rs.getInt("id");
}
```

Here I get error *"column id not not found"*.

Then I changed the query to this, which is working:

```
String selectId = "SELECT id FROM book_store.cart ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
```

I am wondering why the first query is giving me an error and second does not if they are returning the same value?

Comment: Why are you trying to get the latest id? If it is to generate the next id, that is the wrong approach, use an auto-increment column instead and use the JDBC generated keys facility to get the generated id.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Hi Mark, it's because of this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62853215/problem-with-logic-of-book-store-application-in-java-ee i'm having problem with logic of book store. I have table cart and i want to ask `if(cart==null) insert into cart else //here i want to return existing cart`(which is last id in cart). I'm probably wrong to return last id but i'm not sure how to solve it. I would appreciate if u go to link and check it out. Thanks

Comment: Please be careful with such logic: the latest cart in the database is not necessarily the latest cart of your current user. If your logic is wrong, you might be sharing carts across users.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel i understand that, but how to return right cart to the right user?

Comment: There are multiple solutions, like associating the user with the cart (this does allow for multiple carts per user), or the cart with the user (only a single cart per user). There are likely also other solutions.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel i will try that. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first query will return a row with a column name of `MAX(id)`.

Not the most useful name for a column, so change the query to set an alias for that column like this

```
SELECT MAX(id) id FROM book_store.cart
```

And now the column will be called `id` and the `rs.getInt("id")` will work

Comment: I get stuck on most stupid problems, thank you so much! I would really appreciated if you can check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62853215/problem-with-logic-of-book-store-application-in-java  i asked this yesterday and no one answered. It's a little longer but i think it's easy for everyone with any java experience. Thanks again!